# OpenCover testing tool usage in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, nunit, opencover

I am trying to use OpenCover for a calculator application, written in C#.
I have opened it in Visual Studio 2013 and installed the OpenCover and Report Generation packages using the package manager console. I cannot understand the other commands to continue. Specifically what does it mean by `-target<target application>`?

I cannot understand a single step to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install OpenCover it would/should have presented you with a readme.txt that provides a link to the wiki http://www.github.com/OpenCover/OpenCover/wiki/usage - there is also a usage.pdf installed with the tool.

-target means the target application, this can be the app you have just written or a coverage tool such as nunit that would run parts of your application code whilst it is running the supplied tests.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're happy with any code coverage without it specifically needing to be OpenCover, then see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47542095/1695458).**

Using the AxoCover plugin makes it very quick and simple to get your NUnit tests displaying their code coverage.